# PL/SQL Exception Translation

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, ora-06553

I am inserting a new object in my database table, but I keep on retrieving a exception that states....

```
    ERROR:insertproperty:ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for function goto if loop mod null
   package pragma procedure raise return select separate type
   update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   form table call close current define delete fetch lock insert
   open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expec
```

but all I am doing is a simple insert into...

```
function insert(...)
begin
    begin 
     select table_seq.nextval
     into nextval 
     from dual

     begin
     insert into table(id, ....)
     values(nextval,....)
     end 
    end
end
```

the dots are all optional so not really needed.

Comment: The error message mentions `EXCEPTION` and you sanitize your code, removing `EXCEPTION`, and probably its surrounding context. How are we supposed to help, when you remove the chunk of code that is getting the complaint?

Comment: @Shannon Severance Sorry about that, but All i really wanted was someone to explain the exception to me. Not really have anything to do with the code, hence the name "Exception Translation"

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that there is a syntax problem near the `EXCEPTION` keyword.  But your code outline doesn't indicate that any of your blocks have an exception section.  That makes it rather difficult for us to provide much assistance.

In a comment, you seem to indicate that at least one of the blocks in your outline has an exception section.  Can you post the actual code (or at least a more detailed outline that includes the syntax of whatever exception block is generating the error)?

Additionally, in a comment, it sounds like you do have a `RETURN` statement in your function that is returning some sort of status code.  It is almost always a mistake to use return codes from functions-- it is much more robust to simply throw an exception (or even better, allow the exception that was generated to propagate up).  It is generally a mistake to write a function in PL/SQL that does DML-- if you're doing DML, you almost always want that to be done in a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return a value. I think you want to make it a PROCEDURE (and add some semicolons, an "AS" keyword etc.):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE insert_proc(...)
AS
BEGIN
   begin 
      select table_seq.nextval
        into nextval 
        from dual;

      begin
         insert into table(id, ....)
         values(nextval,....);
      end;
   end;
END insert_proc;
```

If you are using Oracle 11g, you can omit the call to the DUAL table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE insert_proc(...)
AS
BEGIN
   insert into table(id, ....)
   values(nextvatable_seq.nextval,....);
END insert_proc;
```

N.B. You should add an exception section to handle any common exceptions that might occur, e.g. constraint violations etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: yeah sorry, it returns a value in the end, but i didnt' really include that part. basically at the end if it throws an exception then return a negative number which i didn't include, but what does the exception mean?

Comment: You are missing a keyword in your function declaration. Can you post the actual syntax?